# InvalidAudienceForResource when using OfficeJS REST Token

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We are using the REST token provided by the OfficeJS API and calling the Outlook API to update item properties. For one particular customer with an on premise Exchange server we are receiving the following error:

**Details**

- Microsoft Exchange Server 2016
- Windows Outlook 2016, Version: 16.0.12527.20278

> EWS Error: We are having issues contacting EWS. Please try again in a few seconds. If the problem persists, please contact support with the following details.","source":"EWS","details":{"moreInfo":"The audience claim value is invalid for current resource.

Is this a known issue?

Comment: Did something change recently in the environment?  Was there a new manifest deployed, or the URL to the application changed?

Comment: No, we only have one customer facing this issue.

Comment: Although this article seems dated, it does seem to indicate that there are architectual requirements for REST API to work.  Perhaps a Fiddler trace might shed more light on it.  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/on-premises-architectural-requirements-for-the-rest-api/ba-p/605609

Comment: @SameeraJayaseckara Which CU of Exchange 2016 is the customer running?

Comment: CU version is 15.1.1978.0

Comment: Which endpoint are you using when you receive this error? Are you able to provide any more information about the call context, error logs, or repro steps to help us diagnose this issue?

Comment: We have sent the Fiddler logs